# Screen does not refresh after a Stream has changed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

In my Flutter application my `'/'` route is set to Wrapper(), 
In that Wrapper, I have the following:

```
FirebaseUser user = context.watch<FirebaseUser>();

    if (user == null) {
      return Authentication();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
```

The problem I a having with this code is that if I update the Navigation stack with, for example, `Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/login")`, the return statement from above does not update the screen.

For instance, after the `Authentication()` page I redirect to either Login or Register page with Flutter's Navigator. And if the state of the `FirebaseUser` changes from one of those pages, I do not get redirected to `Home()` from my `Wrapper()`. I need to update the screen manually (press back on Android Emulator) and only then will I be redirected to `Home()`.

I am also open to complete 'redesigns' of the structure of my app if needed.
EDIT: Also, do I even need the wrapper? I implemented it to make sure the user get to the right screen, since I did not know if there are any workarounds with the state of the app. Can I get by with just using the navigation without all of the Wrapper nonsense?

Comment: You can check out this: https://github.com/tattwei46/flutter_login_demo

Comment: Also, it will be helpful if you show a screenshot of your widget tree. The problem is that your provider might be not high enough to reach in the widget tree.

Comment: the issue there seems to be related to the routes stack that is created when one uses Navigator. I'm not sure yet how to solve this but maybe flutter navigation 2.0 could help. I just faced the same issue and when I tried changing the App to having only two pages (login and home w/ a logout button, without any Navigator) it worked normally. I'll try navigator 2.0 and see what happens.